# Organizar ListView pela coluna

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho um ListView com 2 colunas : Modelo | Variantes .
Ao clicar no topo quero que a tabela se organize de acordo com a coluna que eu clicar

Comment: Se existem várias colunas, por que você não usa uma `ListView` ou um `GridView` no lugar de `ListBox`?

Comment: Estou Usando um ListView , me confundi.

Comment: Usa uma Gridview... é mais facil!
GridView.Sort Method (String, SortDirection)